# Is "Lightbringers and Rainmakers" a standalone work, or is it an excerpt of "The Rise of Ransom City"?

Tags: felix-gilman

I just finished reading [*The Half-Made World*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003P8QSAA). It was great. I'd love to read more, and I know that [*The Rise of Ransom City*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008E8NO76) is a sequel of sorts.

I also see on Amazon that there is a short piece entitled ["Lightbringers and Rainmakers"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004K1ES4O) (also available on [Tor.com](http://www.tor.com/stories/2010/10/lightbringers-and-rainmakers) for free). Since it's also written from Harry Ransom's first-person POV (unlike *The Half-Made World*, or [the other short fiction that shares the same world on his website.](http://felixgilman.com/writings/smilers-brochure.pdf)), My natural inclination is to think that this was an *excerpt* released early, or a short piece that later became the whole novel. Is this the case? Or does it stand on it's own as a separate work that I should read before *The Rise of Ransom City*?

Answer (score 1):

According to the reviews on [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10320885-lightbringers-and-rainmakers), the story should be read *after* The Half-Made World and forms a bridge between the earlier book and The Rise of Ransom City

His publisher; [Macmillan Press](http://us.macmillan.com/lightbringersandrainmakers/FelixGilman#authors) describes it as a "*companion*" to THMW.

> Felix Gilman was born in London and studied history at Oxford before
>   moving to the U.S. to live with his wife, Sarah. His first novel,
>   Thunderer, appeared in 2008, followed by sequel Gears of the City in
>   2009. "Lightbringers and Rainmakers" is a companion to his new novel The Half-Made World, first in a new series, which was released by Tor
>   Books in October 2010.